# Google glass bluetooth tether connectivity issues

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass

I currently have a pair of google glass paired through bluetooth to an LG G2.
My LG G2 can access the internet and my network without an issue.
Glass can search web pages and browse the internet without an issue.
My custom application works fine through WiFi on my phone and on glass, if glass is going through WiFi.

However I have a custom application that I made that cannot connect to a server on my network through the bluetooth tether.  I haven't been able to find anything regarding special permissions or programming changes that would need to be done when tethering, so am I missing something critically important here?

It is absolutely critical that I use my phone's wifi because it supports 5 Ghz WiFi and 2.4 Ghz is completely saturated where I am.

Currently I am trying to use the libstreaming example 3 to stream video to a server:
https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/wiki/Using-libstreaming-with-Wowza-Media-Server

My manifest has been modified to include

```
android.permissions.BLUETOOTH
android.permissions.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

I've also hard coded my server IP address and the correct settings to automatically start the video stream inside onCreate.  This all works on my phone but I get a connection timeout when connecting through glass when bluetooth tethered.

Comment: Are you able to connect to any other services other than your server while tethered to bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, through google search I can go to web pages such as wikipedia and youtube.

Comment: Can you ping the wowza media server from glass while tethered to BT?

Comment: A ping from my phone works correctly, a ping from glass does nothing. I get the following: "PING 192.168.10.111 <196.168.10.111> 56 (84) bytes of data."  With no output after that.  No time out, no error messages.  Pinging google does a proper DNS lookup but then it doesn't go through either.

Comment: Sort of sounds like the connection sharing on your phone is messed up. Have you tried disabling/enabling bluetooth and the personal hotspot (assuming you're using iOS)? Perhaps try tethering to a different device to eliminate your phone as a the potential issue.

Comment: I just tested with a Smsung Galaxy Note 10.1.  I can google search and load web content.  But I cannot access my server through the tablet.

Comment: Perhaps it's not possible for bluetooth-tethered devices to connect to the local area network of the device they are tethered to. I might be worth asking this on [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) or [network engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/660756/does-the-bluetooth-adapter-require-an-ip-address-in-a-lan) sort of addresses that, but it's inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

With the following steps I was able to connect from Google Glass to a server socket:

- enable android.permissions.INTERNET to the manifest file
- on the android phone: settings->wireless..more->tethering & hotspot ->activate bluetooth tethering

maybe this helps...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, when data is connected you do not get an ip address... Thus your socket isn't really able to connect. Data requests are sent through bluetooth and really it is your phone making the request....

I will try to look into it, but right now bluetooth connectivity yields an ip address of 0.0.0.0